# Why are the number of reported sex crimes so high at Ivy League Schools?

Tags: united-states, academic-life, sexual-misconduct

It seems like the % of sex crimes (rape, statutory rape, etc.) are way higher at ivy league schools / schools with a low admission rate compared to other schools.  Other crimes like assault and robbery are higher at schools with a higher admission rate.

https://www.collegecrime.org/schools 
https://www.collegecrime.org/school/5225/criminal/harvard-university

Why is this?

Comment: I can't find it now, but I'm quite certain I once saw a question around here similarly asking about why cases of sexual misconduct occur so frequently in North American universities compared to some other places, and one of the answers pointed out that whether the university is rather a large campus with little daily contact to the outside world, or a set of buildings spread across a city, largely contributes to the perception whether certain cases of misconduct happened "at the university" or "somewhere in the city".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Also, in my experience, Americans tend to be much more aware of these things than others, particularly Europeans.  As an American living in central Europe, I witnessed what *I* would have considered sexual assault on a regular basis that was silently accepted.

Comment: @JeffL. It's not necessarily awarness: personal boundaries vary a lot across countries, whether it refers to private life, workplace behaviour or sexual behaviour.

Comment: @JeffL. I don't think that rape and robbery are silently accepted in Europe. But sexual assault as using a position to put pressure to subordinates, this could be more prominent in Europe, and dependent on culture, personal boundaries etc.

Answer (score 11):

Via [NBC](http://www.nbcnewyork.com/news/local/Campus-Safety-Sex-Assault-Drug-Weapons-Arrest-Interactive-Map-Investigation-274356501.html), these numbers may reflect higher levels of reporting, rather than more crime:

> Experts do not think the reason is because more sex crimes are actually occurring on Ivy campuses.
>
> "I think higher numbers of students reporting sexual offenses suggests there is a process in place that students feel comfortable going to," said Suzanne Goldberg, a Columbia law professor who helped write the university's policy on gender based misconduct.
>
> Goldberg says recording more sex complaints is not necessarily a bad thing.
>
> "I think actually all the data suggests that sexual violence including rape, including sexual harassment, including sexual exploitation and domestic violence, takes place fairly evenly across the population at universities."

[Inside Higher Ed](https://www.insidehighered.com/news/2016/06/13/advocates-warn-against-ranking-colleges-handling-sexual-assault-based-clery-data) similarly reports:

> While it makes for good headlines, researchers and advocates say using federal reporting data to assess the prevalence of campus sexual assault or to rank the relative safeness of individual colleges is ill advised and even irresponsible.
>
> “It is really misguided to use sexual assault reports as rankings, because schools with higher rates are actually doing a better job of encouraging reporting and addressing the issue,” Laura Dunn, founder and executive director of the victims' advocacy organization SurvJustice, said. “By ranking schools with higher rates as unsafe, the media's uninformed coverage is actually discouraging schools from better addressing campus sexual assault. We don't want to push reports into the shadows; we want [assaults] to be reported and dealt with appropriately.”

and

> Clery data should not be used as a tool for comparing or ranking institutions, said Mary P. Koss, a professor of public health at the University of Arizona and a pioneering researcher on the prevalence of campus sexual assault.
>
> “It is a completely, totally invalid assumption,” Koss said. “In some respects, high numbers can be good. If you’re revamping your approach to sexual assault, you would actually expect the number of reports to go up. But even those high rates are not credible, as they are just the number of reports, not actual assaults. The bigger story is looking at those numbers in the context of how many rapes are being identified by climate surveys.”

Comment: What I've always found astonishing is that there is even a single case of sexual assault among students. As far as I recall, in the last twenty years in my country a few cases of sexual misconduct have been reported and judged in courts, but they involved a professor and a student, never just two students or more students.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano To infer from this that there are no (or few) instances of sexual assault among students is the same mistake the OP makes. The number of _reports_ of sexual violence may tell us more about the reporting climate than about the number of crimes. Here are some [statistics on Italy](http://www.istat.it/en/files/2015/09/EN_Violence_women.pdf?title=Violence+against+women+-+23+Sep+2015+-+Full+text.pdf).

Comment: I'm quite aware that unfortunately in Italy there is a serious problem of violence against women, especially in family contexts, with a number of homicides that is shocking. However, after almost thirty years inside a university, and having had many female friends and students, I feel confident in saying that, compared to the outside world, interstudent violence is almost unheard of.

Comment: @Massimo Why do you think your friends or students would tell you about something like this, if it happened?

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano -- over the course of their lives, about 1/3 of women will experience sexual assault and/or rape. That would suggest that a sizable fraction of your female acquaintances are among them. For how many of them do you know that to be true? -- As a man, you are not likely to see or hear about the actual size of the problem.

Comment: It's a long and delicate discourse, and it's impossible to exhaust here in comments. For what concerns friends, there's absolutely no doubt about whether they would tell me something about this or not, for many reasons I cannot delve into here. For what concerns students, of course there can be doubts and I cannot swear about it. @WolfgangBangerth "For how many of them do you know that to be true?": _One hundred percent_.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano - You may be right, that the rates are low where you are.  But I would imagine that your sample set was extremely small.  So the best you can get from your sample set is a hunch.  You'd have to perform or read some systematic research to go beyond the level of a hunch.

Comment: @aparente001 I tried to find one specific related to universities in Italy and for the moment I couldn't find any. I'll continue to search. I've also looked in the news, but they were all about the issue in US universities

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano - a good starting point might be women's organizations in Italy or Europe.  You could also write a Question on Academia SE!

Comment: @aparente001 I already checked the statistics from those organizations in Italy. There's no indication that there is any usual form of interstudent violence in universities: either it is statistically insignificant with respect to the other environments (which is what I think according to my experience, and claimed before), or it is absolutely hidden, but I doubt that nowadays it could remain hidden for so long if it were significant. It is true that in Italy we don't have US-like campuses, but we have university dormitories anyway.